# How to manually generate an X.509 format RSA certificate?

Tags: security, cryptography, rsa, x509certificate

I'd like to create a dart library that generates RSA certificate but I don't understand the X.509 format or how to encode data using Distinguished Encoding Rules.

Could someone please provide a step by step guide or link one. I've tried using Chat GPT to explain it to me but learning that it uses the X.509 format and encodes the data using Distinguished Encoding Rules is as far as it has gotten me. I need something detailed enough to be useful but simple enough for my brain to understand.

This is the kind of response I've gotten from Chat GPT. It's a good starting point but I cannot go very far with it

```
Generating a X.509 format RSA key pair manually without using any tool is possible but it is a complex process and requires a good understanding of the RSA algorithm and the X.509 standard. Here are the steps involved in manually generating a X.509 format RSA key pair:

Step 1: Generate a prime number
Choose two distinct prime numbers (p and q) that are large enough (at least 2048 bits) and are of similar size. You can generate prime numbers using various algorithms like Miller-Rabin, Sieve of Eratosthenes, etc.

Step 2: Compute the modulus
Calculate the modulus (n) by multiplying p and q. n = p * q.

Step 3: Compute Euler's totient function
Compute the Euler's totient function (φ(n)) of n. φ(n) = (p-1) * (q-1).

Step 4: Choose the public exponent
Choose a public exponent (e) that is relatively prime to φ(n). Typically, the value 65537 (0x10001 in hexadecimal) is used as the public exponent.

Step 5: Compute the private exponent
Compute the private exponent (d) such that (e * d) mod φ(n) = 1. You can use the extended Euclidean algorithm to find d.

Step 6: Encode the public key
Encode the public key using the X.509 standard. The public key consists of the modulus (n) and the public exponent (e).

Step 7: Encode the private key
Encode the private key using the PKCS#8 standard. The private key consists of the modulus (n), the public exponent (e), and the private exponent (d).

Step 8: Generate the self-signed X.509 certificate
Create a self-signed X.509 certificate that contains the public key and other information like the common name, issuer, validity period, etc. The certificate should be signed using the private key.

As you can see, manually generating a X.509 format RSA key pair is a complex process that requires a good understanding of the RSA algorithm and the X.509 standard. Therefore, it is recommended to use a tool like OpenSSL or a similar tool to generate RSA key pairs and X.509 certificates.
```

I've already created some libraries that I plan on using:

- [number_system](https://pub.dev/packages/number_system)
- [einfache_krypto](https://pub.dev/packages/einfache_krypto)

I highly appreciate all the help. Thanks.

Comment: The question is asking for details on 1) generating RSA keypairs and 2) creating an X.509 certificate with the RSA public key. Each one of those is quite large a topic. The Q&A format of SO is designed for more specific questions. You can find many tutorials on these topics elsewhere on the web. Always consult wikipedia as they are a great start. For X.509, ASN.1, and ASN.1 encodings, please at least familiarize yourself with [RFC 5280](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5280). An RFC is by no means a tutorial, but it is fairly top-down so you can drill down as deep as you're comfortable

Comment: For DER encoding of ASN.1 structures, the [Guide to a Subset of ASN.1, BER, and DER](https://luca.ntop.org/Teaching/Appunti/asn1.html) is, believe it or not, a tutorial. I think it's a very painful read, but that's because it's a faithful reflection of the pain of ASN.1 (I'm not a fan of ASN.1 for crypto, but the IETF is). The [wikipedia article on RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) contains more detail than the chatGPT answer. Finally, there's also the [crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) and [security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchanges to consult

Comment: You'd be better off to create a good wrapper library around native code. You can throw away all that code if you don't know about side channel attacks. Creating a good ASN.1 library takes at least 2 months for somebody who already knows the standard, and then they are still likely to create *some piece of crap* (eh, other Maarten?).